# Unexpected values in a Concurrent program

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a short program in order to check the effect of the race condition. Class Counter is given below. The class has two methods to update the counter instance variable c. On purpose, I added a random code in both methods , see related code variable i, to increase the probability of their interleaved execution when accessed by two threads.

In the main() method of my program, I put in a loop the following code

```
t1=new Thread() { public void run(){objCounter.increment();}};   
   t2=new Thread() { public void run(){objCounter.decrement();}};
   t1.start();
   t2.start();
   try{
   t1.join();
   t2.join();
   }
   catch (InterruptedException IE) {}
```

Then I printed the different values of c in the objCount... Further to the expected values 1, 0, -1, the program displays also the unexpected values: -2,-1, -3, even 4

I sincerely can't see what threads interleaving will lead to the unexpected values given above. Ideally, I should look at the assembly code to see how the statements c++, and c-- got translated...regardless, I Think there is another reason behind the unexpected values.

```
class Counter{
private volatile int c=0;
public   void increment(){
    int i=9;
    i=i+7;
    c++;
    i=i+3;

}
public  void decrement() {
    int i=9;
    i=i+7;
    c--;
    i=i+3;        
   }
public int value(){ return c; }

}
```

Comment: `c++`/`c--` isn't an atomic operation, even on a volatile variable: it's a read, an increment and a write. The read and the write may be interleaved with the actions of other threads.

Comment: I know it is not....c++ will be highly likely converted to copy C into a register, increment the register, copy register into memory. Based on the above, I was expecting only 1, 0, -1 as possible outputs..yet I am getting more

Comment: _Yesterday, I posted this question but it was unwisely closed as whoever did it; did not read my whole question carefully_ More than one person needs to vote to close a question. I believe it is three. But even after a question is closed, it can be edited which makes it eligible for re-open. Did you try editing your closed question?

Comment: @Abra not necessarily 3 people; a gold badge holder can dupe-hammer a question single-handedly.

Comment: @user2005893 please can you post a [mcve], so we can see exactly what you are doing to get these values: they are indeed strange.

Comment: "I put in a loop the following code" do you create a new instance of `Counter` in that loop too, or do you reuse the same instance?

Comment: @Abra, I was not able to edit it

Comment: @Andy, you pointed me to my silly mistake..the Counter instance was outside the loop and that's why I ended up getting those unexpeted values. I added another method in Counter to reset to c to zero. I called this function at the start of each loop iteration and this fixed the problem. However, by writing the following: Counter1 count outside the loop; then within the loop  before creating t1 and t2, I wrote count=new Counter(); I got the following compilation error pointing to t1=new Thread()....and t2:

Comment: However, by writing the following: "Counter1 count;"outside the loop; then within the loop  before creating t1 and t2 in my first block of code posted above, I wrote "count=new Counter1()"; I got the following compilation error pointing to t1=new Thread()....and t2: Multiple markers at this line
 - Local variable count defined in an enclosing scope must be final or 
  effectively final
 - overrides run

Answer (score 0):

Even if you marked an int as volatile, that kind of operations are not atomic. Try to replace your primitive int with a Thread Safe Class like:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Or just access it through a synchronyzed method.

Answer (score 0):

> I put in a loop the following code

You don't show reinitialization of the `objCounter` variable; this suggests that you're reusing the variable between loop iterations.

As such, you can get -2 from the situation resulting in -1 (e.g. Thread 1 read, Thread 2 read, T1 write, T2 write) happening twice.

In order to avoid reusing the state from previous runs, you should declare and initialize the `objCounter` variable inside the loop:

```
for (...) {
  Counter objCounter = new Counter();
  t1=new Thread() { public void run(){objCounter.increment();}};   
  t2=new Thread() { public void run(){objCounter.decrement();}};
  // ... Start/join the threads.
}
```

It can't be declared before the loop and initialized inside the loop, because then it is not effectively final, which is required (that, or actual finality) to refer to it inside the anonymous classes of the threads.

---

> On purpose, I added a random code in both methods , see related code variable i, to increase the probability of their interleaved execution when accessed by two threads.

As an aside, this your random code does nothing of the sort.

There is no requirement for Java to execute the statements in program order, only to *appear* to execute them in the program order from the perspective of the current thread.

These statements may be executed before or after the `c++/--`, if they are executed at all - they could simply be detected as useless.

You may as well just remove this code, it really only serves to obfuscate.